# How to handle excel file which is hidden?

Tags: excel, apache-poi

When a file is hidden, the FileOutputStream method can't use normally.But POI only provide this one method to handle excel, so how to handle excel file which is hidden with POI?

Comment: Why can't you use a FileOutputStream? Just specify the whole file path and it ought to be fine

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the key point is: it is a hidden file.You can't open a FileOutputStream for a hidden file with JAVA language, so do POI.

Comment: Really? I can just fine on Linux. Is this perhaps a platform specific issue? (You've not tagged your question with any platforms so it's hard to know)

Comment: U are right,it has called a native method open().Thanks all the same.